# Invalid JSON Error in console when child window in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, json, childwindow

Hi am using the below code for open child in chrome but that window open as empty window. but it works fine in Firefox.

> Am using jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Source code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  popup = window.open("http://192.168.1.104:1007/print/coupon", "Popup", "width=500,height=500");
  popup.focus();
</script>
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught Invalid JSON: <script type="text/javascript">
                        popup = window.open("http://192.168.1.104:1007/print/coupon", "Popup", "width=500,height=500");
                        popup.focus();
                      </script>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the Function?

for eg: `onclick="myFunction()"`

then

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
.....
</script>
```

Here is the js: https://jsfiddle.net/v1sg2baz/#&togetherjs=OtSaoVI5Lt